# Base 4 Mathematics

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

I have an homework question but I'm having hard time to understand the context. Here is the question:

> 3. Assume that you are using 3-digit number system with base r = 4 (and n = 3). Assume also that you are using four’s complement scheme
>      to represent signed integers and for subtraction operation.
>
> a.    Show the range of integers that can be represented 4s complement
>   signed number system.

In the (a), I tried to use formula that I derived from 2's complement but it seems that somehow it's not correct. 
$$[-4^{n-1},4^{n-1}-1]$$

This formula gives `[-16,15]` but shouldn't the numbers whose leading digit is 0 and 1 be positive? That gives positive numbers from 0 to 31, but I don't know what to do with the negative ones.

Comment: Isn't this the whole idea of $n$'s complement scheme?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean?

Comment: I'll explain it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on wiki's entry on [Method of complements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements).

- The **radix complement** of an n digit number $y$ in radix $b$ is $b^n-y$.
- The **diminished radix complement** is $( b^n - 1 )-y$.
- The **two's complement** refers to the radix complement of a number in base $2$.
- The **ones' complement** refers to the diminished radix complement of a number in base $2$.
- The **four's complement** refers to the radix complement of a number in base $4$.
- The **fours' complement** refers to the diminished radix complement of a number in base $5$.

Assuming you have copied down the method of complements correctly and it is indeed four's
complement we are talking about, a $n$-digit negative number $-x$ will be represented by
the string corresponds to $4^n - x$. For example, the number $-1$ will be represented as
a string with $n$ characters of '$3$'.

In general, the legal range for numbers will be $[-\frac{4^n}{2}, \frac{4^n}{2} -  1 ]$.
In certain sense, working with numbers in four's complement is like
working with ordinary integers under modulus arithmetic with modulus equal to $4^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I came up with that already but there is something that I don't understand. If there are 31 positive numbers, they are the numbers whose MSB are 0 or 1, and the negative ones' MSB are 2 or 3, right?. I usually calculate 2's complements by taking the negative of MSB in binary form. So 111 = -2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = -1 in decimal. This one doesn't work on the numbers that start with 3 in 4's complement. 300 = -3*4^2 = -48, but it should be complement of 16. What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: @MertToka Yes, non-negative numbers are those whose MSB are either $0$ or $1$ and negative numbers are those with $2$ or $3$. For taking 4's complement, I don't understand what you are doing. This is what I will do: $$300_{4} \xrightarrow{\text{flip all bits}} 033_{4} \xrightarrow{+1} 100_{4} = 16_{10}$$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea of the $r$'s complement scheme.

Namely, say we have some base $r$ in which we have $n$-digit numbers. Normally these numbers would be identified with $[0,r^n-1]$, e.g. $r=2,n=4$ gives you numbers

> 0000 to 1111

which are (in base 10) equal to $[0,31]=[0,r^n-1]$.

But, when we use $r$'s complement scheme, the first digit of our number in base $r$ will indicate the sign of that number, e.g. again with $r=2, n=4$:

> 1010

will be equal to -1. This should explain your interval $[-16,15]$